# react-native onpress conflicts with onchangetext

Tags: react-native

code:

```
export default class app extends Component {
    state={
        name:''
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <TextInput onChangeText={this.handle}></TextInput>
                <TouchableOpacity
                     onPress={this.handleSubmit(this.state.name)}>
                     <Text>go</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
    handle=(text)=>{
        this.setState({name:text})
    }
    handleSubmit=(name)=>{
        alert(name)
    }
}
```

**every time I enter text,The handleSubmit function will use，why？**

```
<TouchableOpacity
        onPress={()=>this.handleSubmit(this.state.name)}>
        <Text>go</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**If i write like this，The problem is solved，but why？**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handleSubmit function invoked automatically every time when the render cycle occurs the component so when the text changes occur and that's why the function automatically invokes so you have to put the arrow function to must call when they go button press event occurs.

as you are using () here in the this.handleSubmit(this.state.name).